# Use Git dependencies with npm and Node on Heroku

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, npm

I have this package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "coffee-script": "1.1.3"
    , "express": "2.5.0"
    , "less": "1.1.5"
    , "jade": "0.17.0"
    , "connect-redis": "1.2.0"
    , "hiredis": "0.1.13"
    , "redis": "0.7.1"
    , "bcrypt": "0.4.1"
    , "promised-io": "0.3.0"
    , "jugglingdb": "git://github.com/juggy/jugglingdb.git#master"
    , "nodemailer": "0.2.3"
  }
}
```

and I want to deploy to Heroku. It works fine locally with npm version 1.0.105, but it chokes on Heroku (I updated the npm there to 1.0.105 as well):

```
   -----> Heroku receiving push
   -----> Fetching custom build pack... done
   -----> Node.js app detected
   -----> Fetching Node.js binaries
   -----> Vendoring node 0.4.7
   -----> Installing dependencies with npm 1.0.105
          npm ERR! git checkout master fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
          npm ERR! Error: `git "checkout" "master"` failed with 128
          npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-Jb2d/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
          npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
          npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:192:12)
          npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
          npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
          npm ERR! or email it to:
          npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
          npm ERR! 
          npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-316-ec2
          npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-C3jD/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-Jb2d/cli.js" "install"
          npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_2yzg7lk83o5m9
          npm ERR! node -v v0.4.7
          npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.105
          npm ERR! git checkout master fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
          npm ERR! 
          npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
          npm ERR!     /tmp/build_2yzg7lk83o5m9/npm-debug.log
          npm not ok
    !     Failed to install dependencies with npm
    !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Also, I do not seem to find a way to get access to that log file in /tmp.

As anyone succeed deploying a Git dependency on Heroku (works fine on ruby side :P) ?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, have you reported it?

Comment: Well Heroku have been silent for a week now....

Comment: It is not heroku's I beilive, It is more like a NPM bug(I thought it is obvious...)

Comment: Why so? It works on my local installation...

Comment: It seems that using the tarball link from the download tab in github instead of the git link is working... I'll use that for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is in their nodejs buildpack.  I've sent a pull request to Heroku with a fix, but I have no idea if or when they'll respond.  Fortunately, there's a not-very-well documented method for using a custom buildpack, which will allow you to work around the issue.  I've forked heroku's nodejs buildpack and fixed the problem - available here:

https://github.com/chrisleishman/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/tree/git_fix

To use this, you're best creating your own github fork of https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs and then merging in my `chrisleishman/git_fix` branch.  E.g. (after forking):

```
git clone git@github.com:@YOUR-GITHUB-NAME@/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
cd heroku-buildpack-nodejs
git remote add chrisleishman git://github.com/chrisleishman/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
git fetch chrisleishman
git merge chrisleishman/git_fix
git push
```

You can then add the `BUILDPACK_URL` config variable to your heroku app.  E.g.

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL="git://github.com/@YOUR-GITHUB-NAME@/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

The next push to heroku should then use the custom buildpack, containing the fix.

Comment: Nice it is working. Do you know if the dependent packages will be updated if I change the git hash without changing the package.json version?

Comment: No, they wont be.  That's a bug in npm.

Comment: Also, I believe this fix has now been merged into the standard buildpack, so this work-around is no longer required.

Comment: Just a note for anyone who comes across this page trying to reference a GitHub repository, make sure to use the "Git Read-Only" URL in your package.json. If you use one of the private URLs you'll get a different error than the one above, but a similar result. The Read-Only URL works fine.

Answer (score 80):

FYI if its on GitHub you can just specify the `username/repository` and npm will do the rest.

```
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "coffee-script": "1.1.3"
    , "express": "2.5.0"
    , "less": "1.1.5"
    , "jade": "0.17.0"
    , "connect-redis": "1.2.0"
    , "hiredis": "0.1.13"
    , "redis": "0.7.1"
    , "bcrypt": "0.4.1"
    , "promised-io": "0.3.0"
    , "jugglingdb": "juggy/jugglingdb"
    , "nodemailer": "0.2.3"
  }
}
```

### Alternatively

Specify one of (`git`/`git+ssh`/`git+http`/`git+https`)`://user@host/repo.git` urls

Fully [documented](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: Cool. How do I specify a branch?

Comment: @betzerra i think thats `juggy/jugglingdb#master` but not sure

Answer (score 43):

I don't know about this package, but I've got others to work with syntax like the following. On heroku, using a http reference to a tar.gz

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "coffee-script": "1.1.3"
    , "express": "2.5.0"
    , "less": "1.1.5"
    , "jade": "0.17.0"
    , "connect-redis": "1.2.0"
    , "hiredis": "0.1.13"
    , "redis": "0.7.1"
    , "bcrypt": "0.4.1"
    , "promised-io": "0.3.0"
    , "jugglingdb": "https://github.com/juggy/jugglingdb/tarball/master"
    , "nodemailer": "0.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup that's what I ended up doing, but I think the git link would be better

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. The syntax is: https://github.com/:organization/:repo/tarball/master

Comment: Worked perfect. I thought I was having proxy issues; but it turned out I was aiming @ the wrong place.

Comment: I had to use the url that the above url redirects to https://codeload.github.com/:org/:repo/legacy.tar.gz/master

Comment: I got an error when trying to use this with /master at the end, taking it off works

Comment: Tried this now in 2021 and can say adding /tarball/master works still. Thanks!

Comment: I changed one lib in `package.json: dependencies { "mux.js": "https://from_github" }`, I can see my code in `node_modules/mux.ts/lib/m2ts/m2ts.js` file. Building a project still use an old code in `dist/video.js` file. No help from `npm install && npm update && npm run build`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can specify [commit-ish](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) to select which commit/branch/... you want to install, in the form `"user/foo-project#commit-ish"`, see [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

An example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "visionmedia/express#some-branch",
    "mocha": "visionmedia/mocha#4727d357ea"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's the same issue at this date, but I experienced an error message that was the same, and I found I was able to resolve it by explicitly specifying the version of node and npm per this page:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue except I was referencing a private git repo. My solution for this was to add a `postinstall` script for the following:

```
{
    "postinstall": "npm update && npm install package-name"
}
```

The update & install makes npm update the private repo to latest. (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's struggling with this using npm 5+ (where `package-lock.json` is a thing), ensure you install the package via command line.

`npm i my_package --save https://github.com/username/repo/archive/v6.5.2.tar.gz`

As of NPM 5.0.3 simply adding it to `package.json` and running `npm i` will not update `package-lock.json` (grrr).