# rebuild compress file vuetable-2 in vue.js

Tags: build, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

i need to edit [vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2). I added  some code in file /node_modules/vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable.vue and rebuild my project. Unfortunately i don't see my changes in project because project get code from node_modules/vuetable-2/dist/vuetable-2.js (it's compress file of Vuetable.vue and other).
Question: how i can rebuild vuetable-2 that my changes would fall into vuetable-2.js

PS npm build don't work

Comment: First of all why are you trying to change something from nodemodules folder? Its not a good idea

Comment: @user7814783 How should I edit the module in this case?

Comment: see the accepted answer here ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095/7814783 )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a node module installed via npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm)