# Editing an NPM module locally

Tags: node.js, npm, module, local, edit

I would like advice on the best practice for modifying an downloaded NPM module (I am working with Webpack/ReactJS).

I have downloaded a package and I wish to remove it from node_modules and package.json and store it in myapp/src where I can edit the package and have the changes immediately available when I am running Webpack dev server.

I am sure there must be a way to do this but I can't seem to find it and it's driving me up the wall!

Thanks.

Comment: As a thought off the top of my head I can suggest using `npm link` for such tasks: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095