# Changes made in files under node_modules

Tags: angular, git, npm, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have changed some files present in node_modules folder. But when I build the application using `ng build -op="app" --base -href="dist" --aot` and when I deploy it to server I see the changes that I made in node_modules were not there. How to overcome this?

I have tried in the below 3 ways

1. I have forked the `ngx-bootstrap` repository into [GIT](https://github.com/krishnag9/ngx-bootstrap)
   Then I have used `npm install https://github.com/krishnag9/ngx-bootstrap/tarball/master` in my project. I have changed `import { BsDaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker'` to `import { BsDaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap-base/src/datepicker'`
   I'm facing the below exception now

   `ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/index.ts
   Module build failed: Error: NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
   The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format
   at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:656:23)
   at plugin.done.then (NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
   @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 49:12-45 54:12-45
   @ ./src/main.ts
   @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
   ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/modal/index.ts
   Module build failed: Error: NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/modal/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
   The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format
   at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:656:23)
   at plugin.done.then (NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
   @ ./src/app/canceltickets/canceltickets.component.ts 21:14-53 22:14-53
   @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
   @ ./src/main.ts
   @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts`
2. Also I have tried `npm install https://github.com/krishnag9/ngx-bootstrap --save-dev` ended up with below error

   `ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/mini-ngrx/state.class.ts(5,39): error TS2305: Module '"NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'queueScheduler'.
   node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/tooltip/tooltip.directive.ts(20,10): error TS2305: Module '"NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'timer'.
   node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-base/src/typeahead/typeahead.directive.ts(18,10): error TS2305: Module '"NPMLINK_TEST/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'from'.`
3. Using `npm link`
   I have cloned the git repository outside of my node_modules
   Next `cd ngx-bootstrap`
   I have executed the command `npm link`
   Redirected to `node_modules` folder
   Here I did `npm link ngx-bootstrap`
   No errors in my console, But the code I have changed is not reflected there and also facing an exception in browser console

   `BsDatepickerContainerComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined
   at ObserveOnSubscriber.scheduleMessage (observeOn.js:99)
   at ObserveOnSubscriber._error (observeOn.js:105)
   at ObserveOnSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
   at BehaviorSubject.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:177)
   at BehaviorSubject.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:97)
   at BehaviorSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
   at ObserveOnOperator.call (observeOn.js:74)
   at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
   at ScanOperator.call (scan.js:72)
   at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)`

Comment: Why are you changing the node_modules files? This is a horrible practice with so many (and unpredictable) side effects

Comment: I can't find any other way!! Just small change. I think so It won't effect the existing features.

Comment: If you change a file inside node_modules, every time anyone runs "npm install" inyour project those files will be overwritten. Do not do this. If you need, clone the original repo, do the changes there and change the dependency in the package.json

Comment: I just need to change the Next & Previous icons in the datepicker https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: @Krishna I don't have enough knowledge about it. I dont think I can help much, But reading your error your can try this:  `Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library.` Have you seen this line in the error, try and configure your `tsconfig` file

Comment: I think , If your node modules are not in node_modules directory then you have to specify new path also in tsconfig file

Comment: ngx-bootstrap-base is inside node_modules folder. But the folders are different when I use npm install ngx-bootstrap --save and npm install https://github.com/krishnag9/ngx-bootstrap --save-dev

Comment: I have tried in 3 ways but no luck

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to change the icon, You can do it like this.
Whenever datepicker is triggered you can just add below lines.

`document.querySelector(".previous span").innerHTML = "<="`

`document.querySelector(".next span").innerHTML = "=>"`

you can change `"=>"` with whatever icon you want to use.

To check this.
Go to https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Then Open any Date Picker and Open console and paste this into console `document.querySelector(".next span").innerHTML = "=>"`

see that next icon changes to `=>`

Comment: Working but If I click the next or previous button to change the month the icon is changing back again

Comment: @Krishna Ohh, ok, I will try to find another work around

Comment: Sure @Bhushan. Thanku

Comment: After building the application, a files is generated with name vendor.bundle.js Can I changed in that file?

Comment: @Krishna , No you should not do that. It's not feasible to change it every time you make a build.

Comment: Okay. Is there anyway then? I need to add TODAY & TOMORROW options also in datepicker. Can I place the folder outside of node_modules and link that to my application

Comment: Read this and try searching for " how to edit npm packages" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm.

Comment: I have tried the above steps. Please check my edited question.

Comment: @Krishna ok.  I will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Any other solution to change that `next` and `previous` icons

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm **patch-package** to **share and persist changes in node_modules**.
Although reply below is in React/React Native section of Stack-overflow, it works for all npm stuff:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871879/11583616

Answer (score -1):

This depends on how you build your app, probably your webpack config. 
Show us your webpack config, you should configure your loader to include the module.

Comment: Not using webpack loader. I mean there is no file like webpack.config.js