# How to trigger modals using show

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm using `this.myModal1.show()` & `this.myModal2.show()` to open the modals. But It is always triggering `myModal1`

My component.ts

```
@ViewChild(ModalDirective) myModal1: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild(ModalDirective) myModal2: ModalDirective;
```

My component.html

```
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #myModal1="bs-modal"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-events-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog otp-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #myModal2="bs-modal"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-events-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog otp-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it working for you? The answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass reference id to `Viewchild` instead of `ModalDirective`

Because with `ModalDirective` it always targets first element with that directive.

```
@ViewChild('myModal1') myModal1: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild('myModal2') myModal2: ModalDirective;
```

Here is Stackblitz link with this implemented.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-p6ohpe

Also see Docs here
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

> You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive
>   matching the selector from the view DOM.

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad on stackblitz? or at your end? because it looks fine on stackblitz

Comment: problem with some z-index. working fine (y).  Can I access the modal if it is in another component.html?

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad If you are looking for a common model, then you can make separate component which can be opened with service with dynamic data. for e.g you can look at this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-fh92s3

Comment: Can we use angular way like this.mymodal1.show() instead of query $('#myModal').modal('show'); I don't want to use jquery

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad Yes you can. Use that example just for reference, and replace jquery with ngx-bootstrap methods.

Comment: I have tried. But I'm unable. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecl7se
Can u pls check

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad Kindly check 'EDIT' at the end of this answer I have updated it with what you want & Upvote it if it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296973/to-reuse-html-content-in-angular-5/50298872#50298872

Comment: Thank u so much. I'm really trying this hard from one week. I have some more issues with angular. Can you please help me resolve them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239986/changes-made-in-files-under-node-modules
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393854/unable-to-change-or-give-custom-css-for-ng-datepicker
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409800/how-to-add-custom-style-to-ngx-bootstrap-tooltip

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad I have added answer to date picker question , see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because @ViewChild(ModalDirective) will target the first element using ModalDirective.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

> You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM.

I think you should use template reference variable like this :

```
@ViewChild('myModal1') myModal1: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild('myModal2') myModal2: ModalDirective;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change:

```
@ViewChild(ModalDirective) myModal1: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild(ModalDirective) myModal2: ModalDirective;
```

To:

```
@ViewChild('myModal1') myModal1: ModalDirective;
@ViewChild('myModal2') myModal2: ModalDirective;
```