# Unable to change or give custom CSS for ng-datepicker

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, ng-modules, ng-build

I am trying to give custom CSS for bs-datepicker. But, its not accepting any change from component.css. I tried adding a class name in the node file of bs-datepicker in node_modules and making css changes using that class name, but the changes are not reflecting when I build the application using ng-build.
 Whatever change I make in node modules, they are reflecting in ng serve local view, but in ng-build , no changes are reflecting.[The image of bs-datepicker is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9YTK.png)

I want to change the positioning, padding, and margin of the datepicker.

```
.bs-datepicker {
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-flow: row wrap;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0 #aaa;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
left: 50%;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

This CSS I want to give to my bs-datepicker

the datepicker is binded to input like

```
<input id="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="datepicker"  class="form-control" type="text" #JourneyDatepicker="bsDatepicker"  bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" [minDate]="minDate"autocapitalize='off' name="journey"  placeholder="Onward Date" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
```