# Customizing ReactJS external package (react-horizontal-timeline)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-shirley-urq7m

This sandbox shows a simple example of the `react-horizontal-timeline` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline).

It provides an API to set a function to trigger when we click each time.

However, I want to add an `onHover` action to trigger an action when we hover each circle icon.

Is there a way to customize such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can change directly on the node_modules folder, but it's not a good practice since it will be reset when you do npm install.

You also can fork the repo [Fork Repo](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), or ask the developer to update their code.
Or maybe you just could modify your own code.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662235/13662847), it's react-native but still relate to your question.