# How to edit a nodejs package?

Tags: npm, node-modules

I have a nodejs project. Within this project, I installed a package via `npm install youtube-dl --save`. So, I not got a `./SuperProject/node_modules/youtube-dl/` directory, whom content is something such as :

```
|-/bin
   +- youtube-dl       <--- what is that thing ?
|-/example
|-/lib
   +- youtube-dl.js    <--- core code and executable ... i guess
|-/scripts
|-/test
|-LICENSE
|-package.json
|-README.md
```

I inspect around, and I see that I could edit `./node_modules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js`, by adding one condition to this package's main file :

```
if (options.format) {
    args.push('--sub-format=' + options.format);
}
```

I instinctively and boldly add this lines to `./node_mudules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js`.

Back to root, I relaunch my script :

```
cd ../../SuperProject
node superproject.js
```

I see no change in my output. Was I right to edit `./node_modules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js` ? Or is `./node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl` the real deal to edit ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm

Comment: Is the package really named `superflash`? There is no package with that name on the public npm repository. Ideally, one would fork the dependency and make this one depend on a patched version.

Comment: That's a dummy name so to make the question shorter. Real package is this https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl but the question is more generic.

Comment: Still, I believe the question would benefit from a more accurate example, so as to better reproduce the issue.

Comment: @E_net4: Done. It's `youtube-dl` for me : )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, edit `youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js`. A `console.log('hello world')` there can proves you that it is the right file to edit. I have no idea what is the `youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl` about.