# Customize Highcharts desc tag

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, chartkick

I'm working with Highcharts on a React view. For accessibility and SEO reasons, I want to **customize** the `desc` tag, but I couldn't figure out how to do it looking in the documentation. Highcharts automatically inserts a `desc` tag like this:

`<desc>Created with Highcharts 6.2.0</desc>`

Is there any way to change this or is this hard-coded?

Comment: You're right it's hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

**(1)** Create a fork from https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts

**(2)** Change the content what hard-coded from

```
<desc>Created with Highcharts 6.2.0</desc>
```

to

```
<desc>foo bar baa</desc>
```

**(3)** Install npm package from GitHub directly

```
npm install https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/tarball/master
```

like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095/3728901

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `<desc>` tag by wrapping `H.SVGRenderer.init` method:

```
H.wrap(H.SVGRenderer.prototype, 'init', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    this.box.children[0].innerHTML = 'Custom description';

});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/42rqezns/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts