# Create React App: Transpile JSX of external package in node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use the [react-scratchblocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scratchblocks) package on my react project.

I've created my project using the create-app-react command.

After importing the package I got the following error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/react-scratchblocks/src/Scratchblocks.js
SyntaxError: /Users/jorge/Documents/React/elimu-analyzer-frontend/node_modules/react-scratchblocks/src/Scratchblocks.js: Unexpected token (45:6)

  43 |     const scripts = this.parseScripts(this.props.code);
  44 |     return (
> 45 |       <div className={this.classNames()}>
     |       ^
  46 |         {scripts.map((script,i) => (
  47 |           <Scratchblock key={i} className="script" script={script}/>
  48 |         ))}
```

I know that the jsx it's not been recognized, but what should I do to make this package work? Remember: i've used the create-rect-app to create my React project.

Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

```
module.exports = function () {

return {
    overrides: [{
        test: ["./node_modules/react-scratchblocks"],
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
    }],
};
}
```

UPDATE 2:
Component that where I import the react-scratchblocks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles.css';
import Fire from '../../config/Fire';
import Realtime from '../Realtime';
import Scratchblocks from 'react-scratchblocks'

function Content(props) {

const [menuOption, setMenuOption] = useState(1);

async function logout() {
    await Fire.logout();
    props.history.push('/');
    console.log('oi');
}

if (menuOption === 0) {
    return (
        <div class='content'>
            <Realtime />
        </div>
    );
}
else if (menuOption === 1) {
    return (
        <div class="content">
            <button onClick={logout}> OUTRA OPÇÃO </button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default withRouter(Content);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the component code in which its throughing this error? Mostly this happens either when we do not `import React from 'react' ` in functional component or when babel is not able to trasnpile.

Comment: @DarpanRangari added in update 2. As you can see i'm import correctly.

Answer (score 11):

I personally suggest you to use `craco` (see [@craco/craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco))

Craco is a powerful tool that allows you to edit built-in `create-react-app` configuration without forcing you to eject the project.

How to install it

- run `npm install @craco/craco --save-dev`
- run `npm install craco-babel-loader --save-dev`
- create `craco.config.js` in the root folder of the project
- update the scripts in `package.json`:

  - `react-scripts start` -> `craco start`
  - `react-scripts build` -> `craco build`
  - ...
- this is the content of the configuration craco file

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const cracoBabelLoader = require('craco-babel-loader')

// manage relative paths to packages
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd())
const resolvePackage = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: cracoBabelLoader,
      options: {
        includes: [
          resolvePackage('node_modules/package-to-transpile'),
          resolvePackage('node_modules/another-package-to-transpile'),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

You can change a lot of other configurations, and I suggest you to give a look at [craco npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)

Credtis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58603207/4277948

Comment: Amazing, concise, answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Create React App (CRA) [only transpiles standard JavaScript syntax](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103#issuecomment-424841694) inside `node_modules`.

This does *not* include JSX compilation. Package react-scratchblocks errors due to [untranspiled JSX](https://github.com/TuringLab/react-scratchblocks/blob/eccf8d5/src/Scratchblocks.js):

> SyntaxError: .../Scratchblocks.js: Unexpected token (45:6)

Statement from maintainers ([link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103#issuecomment-425459196)):

> We only compile valid JavaScript syntax in node_modules. JSX is not valid JavaScript. You are using JSX there.
>
> The reason we've taken this stance is because compiling non-standard syntax tightly couples libraries to build tools.
>
> It's also hard to draw a line once you allow experimental things. Most people will want to use not just JSX, but also experimental transforms like class properties. Or decorators. Now we have to argue with every library maintainer about which transforms we want to support, and which we don't.

Hence package authors would have needed to transpile JSX them selves before distribution.

To transpile JSX manually<sup>1</sup> you can apply the [Babel React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) to `react-scratchblocks` inside `node_modules`:

```
babel node_modules/react-scratchblocks \
  -d node_modules/react-scratchblocks/dist \
  --presets=@babel/preset-react
```

The [build step](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#overrides) might be outsourced into its own [config file](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration) (`transpile.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  overrides: [
    {
      test: ["./node_modules/react-scratchblocks"],
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
    }
  ]
};
```

```sh
babel node_modules/react-scratchblocks \
  -d node_modules/react-scratchblocks/dist \
  --config-file ./transpile.js
```

Then adjust `main` entry inside `node_modules/react-scratchblocks/package.json` to point to the previously transpiled version in `dist`:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
```

[patch-package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567504/5669456) can further automate the process of fixing broken packages.

Remember this is only a workaround - the duty is on package developers to distribute an npm package with standard JavaScript features.

<sup>1</sup> A different alternative would be to adjust Webpack config (only possible with ejected CRA).

Comment: Hi @ford04 . Thanks for your attention. I've create the following babel.config.js file in my root directory as you can see in "UPDATE 1". So what should I do now? It's the right approach? As I saw in the link, looks like it is, but I don't know what to do for now. How do I execute my code to test and everything now? Thanks in advice.