# How to config webpack to transpile files from other lerna packages (ejected from create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm trying to build a lerna package with a `create-react-app` package and a simple component library. My component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

    class Layout extends Component {
        render = () => {
            let style = {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily:
                    "-apple-system, system-ui, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 400
            };
    
            return <div style={style}>{this.props.children}</div>;
        };
    }
    
    export default Layout;
```

And my original `create-react-app` is as follows:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/app/App/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Layout from "@project/webux/lib/Layout";

class App extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <Layout>
                Hello!
            </Layout>
        );
    };
}

export default App;
```

When running, I'm getting the following error:

```
../webux/lib/Layout/index.js
SyntaxError: /Volumes/workspace/dev/packages/webux/lib/Layout/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (5:12):

  3 |
  4 | class Layout extends Component {
> 5 |     render = () => {
    |            ^
  6 |         let style = {
  7 |             fontSize: 14,
  8 |             fontFamily:

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

This error happens because `create-react-app` does not transpile files outside its project. As my component `Layout` resides in another lerna package in another directory, it is not transpiled.

In order to solve it, I've ejected my `create-react-app` application and end up with the following webpack configuration file, where I've added the `====INCLUDED===` piece of code to set the `input` directories (I've added the directory immediately above the project, as this will point to my lerna `\packages` directory, so all packages files are processed:

```
  ...
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                cache: true,
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          //=================== INCLUDED =====================/
          //
          // Included the lenrna packages directory (up directory) 
          // in order to transpile all files from other packages.
          //
          //===================================================
          include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../.."), paths.appSrc],
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              /// Renato Mendes
              /// This was added to support transpiling of monorepo modules.
              /// See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6799
              ///
              /// Original:
              /// include: paths.appSrc
              ///
              include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../.."), path.resolve(paths.lernaRoot + "/packages"), paths.appSrc],
              //              include: paths.appSrc,
              include: [paths.lernaRoot, paths.appSrc],
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                
                // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
                // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
                // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
                // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
                sourceMaps: false,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
    ...
```

I'm still getting the error, as my external component is not getting transpiled.

How to make the above webpack config transpile my code that resides in another package of my lerna project? Any other config missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**The bad news:** This is a common problem. [Create React App doesn't support monorepos](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1333), as of ~3.2.0 / late 2019. If you want to share components between lerna sibling packages, many people either avoid using "CRApp", or, include a build script in their component library packages and commit and export pre-transpiled ES5 files.

**The good news:** I found a fix that seems to work, and *doesn't* require ejecting CRA. Tested with both local build and test deploy to github pages.

It uses [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco), which provides an API for editing CRA's webpack config without ejecting. Craco has plugins which add webpack loaders etc; we'll need [craco-babel-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-babel-loader):

> npm i --save @craco/craco craco-babel-loader

...then there are some further CRACO setup steps, check https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation for the latest. At time of writing, you need to replace the following CRA `scripts` in `package.json`:

- `react-scripts start` => `craco start`
- `react-scripts build` => `craco build`
- `react-scripts test` => `craco test`

Then we need to create a config file, `craco.config.js`, in the root of the CRA/craco package that *receives* ES6+ JSX components from sibling packages, and we need to list the package names to send to babel:

```
// crago.config.js
// see: https://github.com/sharegate/craco

const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const cracoBabelLoader = require('craco-babel-loader')

// Handle relative paths to sibling packages
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd())
const resolvePackage = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: cracoBabelLoader,
      options: {
        includes: [
          // No "unexpected token" error importing components from these lerna siblings:
          resolvePackage('../some-component-library'),
          resolvePackage('../more-components'),
          resolvePackage('../another-components-package'),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `require.context` here instead of specifying each sibling individually?

Comment: great answer, helped me massively, but to resolve the `attempt to import from outside src/` error you also need to do as this answer suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/60353355

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!