# Missing Class Properties Transform Error using Chart.js in React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to generate my first chart in react using Chart.js, and I cannot seem to get over this error. I'm using "react-chartjs-2": "^5.1.0", "chart.js": "^4.1.0", and "react": "^18.2.0".

Here is the Error:

```
    Failed to compile.
    
    ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js
    SyntaxError: /Users/johnwomelsdorf/Documents/Code/Ski-Website-              FrontEnd/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js: Missing class properties transform.
    566 |     };
    567 | class DatasetController {
    
    568 |  static defaults = {};
    |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    569 |  static datasetElementType = null;
    570 |  static dataElementType = null;
    571 |  constructor(chart, datasetIndex){.at transformFile.next (\<anonymous\>)
    at run.next (\<anonymous\>)
    at transform.next (\<anonymous\>)\`
```

And here is my Code:
App.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Navbar from './components/NavBar';
    import Conditions from './components/conditions';
    import Graph from './components/graph';
    import { Data } from './components/data';
    
    class App extends Component {
    state = {
    resorts : \['Okemo', 'Snow', 'Hunter', 'Sunapee', 'Stowe'\],
    resort : 'Okemo'
    };
    
        render() { 
           return (
                <div className='main__wrap'>
                    <Navbar />
                    <div className='conditions__box'>
                        <h2>Current Conditions</h2>
                        <Conditions resort = {this.state.resort} />
                   </div>
                    <div className='graph__box'>
                        <h2>Conditions this year</h2>
                        <Graph chartData={Data}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            );
        };
    
    }
    
    export default App;
```

graph.jsx:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Chart as ChartJS } from "chart.js/auto"
    import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
    
    function Graph(chartData) {
    return \<Line data={chartData} /\>;
    }
    
    export default Graph;
```

data.js:

```
    export const Data = {
        labels: \[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\],
        datasets: \[
        {
            label: "% Lifts Open",
            data: \[33, 40, 80, 90, 100, 60\]
            //borderColor: "rgba(19, 49, 92, 1)",
            //backgroundColor: "rgba(19, 49, 92,0.2)",
        },
        {
            label: "% Trails Open",
            data: \[15, 30, 60, 95, 95, 45\]
            //borderColor: "rgba(141, 169, 196, 1)",
            //backgroundColor: "rgba(141, 169, 196,0.2)",
        },
        {
            label: "% Terrain Open",
            data: \[9, 23, 65, 83, 90, 34\]
            //borderColor: "rgba(19, 64, 116, 1)",
            //backgroundColor: "rgba(19, 64, 116,0.2)",
        }
        ]
    };
```

Thank you, hoping this is a simple misunderstanding on my part.

I have tried changing the shape of the data, as well as the way it is called by the graph.

Comment: are you able to compile classes using your compiler setup? Are you using babel to transpile your code? or webpack? or are you use create-react-app? How are you setting up your project

Comment: I looked at my babel.config.js file and I have `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` that might help you to add that in if you're using babel?

Comment: Hello Coty. I just used create-react-app and then used yarn to install packages.

Comment: do you have eslint configured yourself?

Comment: It could be because modules are not being transpiled from the node_modules/ folder hmm

Comment: without ejecting from create-react-app and configuring things yourself, I think you could maybe copy or move those node_modules outside of the node_modules folder into your own folder and pull from the new location (that would be outside of node_modules/) and it might start transpiling them

Comment: the chart.js/ folder and the react-chartjs-2 folders/modules

Comment: or going deeper you might be able to get away with doing something like mentioned in here and running `babel` at the command line on the node_modules/ good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761818/create-react-app-transpile-jsx-of-external-package-in-node-modules

Comment: Are you able to solve. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. Just downgrade your chart-js and react-chartjs-2 version.

I am using [Chart Js .v3](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/chartjs-v3)