# Modify npm package outside npm modules folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-package

I am using **react-gantt-timeline** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gantt-timeline ) library and need to modify css and some javascript to meet my demand. I tried to fork and then link back my project in which I was successful but my it's not a good solution since I need to also maintain the forked project. 
In that case what will be the standard way to modify the npm package outside of npm module? 
One way I was thinking is to import the css and javascript locally and then modify it. But I was unable to refer them properly.

Comment: The fork is the best way. A more complete answer is here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm)

Comment: Forking will not be accepted, because our main project is in another source control and management don't want to maintain another library in another source control. Is there any way to instantiate the css and files in our project and from there modify them?