# Looking for help to make npm/pdfjs-dist work with Webpack and Django

Tags: javascript, django, npm, webpack, pdfjs-dist

I've been trying for a few hours replacing a link-based pdf.js with an npm install of `pdfjs-dist`, since I noticed that my links were not meant to be used as cdns and could become unstable as [described here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10997#issuecomment-513939192).

I could not find much documentation on how to make that work other than a few examples, and when Webpack is involved they are mostly with React, while I am simply using ES6 in a Django framework (static compiling on the desired django directory, without using the webpack-plugin.)

After [exchanging several messages](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10838#issuecomment-678661860) with one of the guys that work on pdf.js it seemed that my compiling errors were probably due to how Webpack handles internally the library. Here's what I am seeing:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack/lib/web/FetchCompileAsyncWasmPlugin' in '/home/giampaolo/dev/KJ_import/KJ-JS/node_modules/worker-loader/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/cjs.js
 @ ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js
 @ ./src/js/views/pdfViews.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack/lib/web/FetchCompileWasmPlugin' in '/home/giampaolo/dev/KJ_import/KJ-JS/node_modules/worker-loader/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/cjs.js
 @ ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js
 @ ./src/js/views/pdfViews.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/giampaolo/dev/KJ_import/KJ-JS/node_modules/webpack/lib/node'
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js 11:1-18
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/cjs.js
 @ ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js
 @ ./src/js/views/pdfViews.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     1 asset
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/src-select.html] 4.57 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
Child worker-loader node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js:
              Asset      Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.worker.js  1.33 MiB  pdf.worker  [emitted]  pdf.worker
    Entrypoint pdf.worker = index.worker.js
    [./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js] 1.25 MiB {pdf.worker} [built]
    [./node_modules/process/browser.js] 5.29 KiB {pdf.worker} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Theoretically the `pdfjs-dist` should come with a zero configuration file, without even needing to set up a worker for it, so code like the one below *should* work:

```
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'

////////////////////////////////////////////
//// instantiate pdf
export const pdfView = () => {
  // pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'index.worker.js';

  // var defined through a Django template tag
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfData.myPdfDoc)

  pdfData.myPdf = loadingTask.promise.then(pdf => {
    pdfData.pdfTotalPageN = pdf.numPages;
    return pdf;
  })
}
```

but it doesn't get compiled, and I would really appreciate some pointers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, what did you ended up doing?

Comment: So far I remained with the CDN approach. I am tempted to open an issue in Webpack, since the guys at Mozilla were helpful but pointed at an internal error in WP. I have asked for feedback in WP's gitter chat ( https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack ) with no luck...

Comment: Update: I finally implemented it with an install, following the selected answer from @Siddhesh. The only amendment required to my code was importing with `import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'` instead than `import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'`

Comment: Aaaand... after just a few days working and a Webpack update (from wp4 to wp5) `pdfjs-dist` went belly up again. Half a day lost trying to figure it out. I went back to a CDN. A simple `<script>` in the `html` with the pdf.min.js link, a `pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/[same_version!]/pdf.worker.min.js"` in the code before calling `pdfjsLib` (`const loadingTask =
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfData.myPdfDoc)`) and the `loadingTask` promise, no other imports. Quite a bit easier.

Comment: I think the webpack import is now working again. I'm getting no set worker warnings with pdflibJs version 3.3.122. and webpack 5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue seems to arise due to `esModule` option introduced in `worker-loader@3.0.0`.

The [fix for this was merged](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/commit/dee0c29f6fe6ce6b0b3605527353a1089d674af0) in `(pre-release) pdjs-dist@2.6.347`

You can fix this by either upgrading `pdfjs-dist` to `v2.6.347` OR downgrading `worker-loader` to `v2.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for letting us know @Siddikesh. Plan to test it as soon as I get a moment.

Comment: Wow I upgraded pdfjs-dist to pre-release version and that error vanished. I have put a lot of hours trying to fix that but you saved the day. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! After upgraded pdfjs to 2.6.347 via ```yarn upgrade pdfjs-dist@2.6.347``` and my worker-loader is 3.0.5. Everything worked.

Answer (score 7):

I just had to solve this issue myself...

This issue

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/giampaolo/dev/KJ_import/KJ-JS/node_modules/webpack/lib/node'
```

Is caused by `worker-loader` loading `NodeTargetPlugin`, which in turn runs `require("module")` which I think (but I'm not 100%) is for native node modules, which when running Webpack targeted for web is not relevant

This issue can be mitigated with Webpack config

```json
{
  node: {
    module: "empty"
  }
}
```

Afterwards, things move along farther, but I needed further mitigations:

```js
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/webpack";
```

This runs `pdfjs-dist/webpack.js:27` which is

```js
var PdfjsWorker = require("worker-loader!./build/pdf.worker.js");
```

Which is attempting to load `pdf.worker.js` (which `worker-loader` should be packaging) and then tries to instantiate the class:

```js
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new PdfjsWorker();
```

The issue I had was that Webpack packaged `pdf.worker.js` as an esModule (the default for `worker-loader`), so the way it was require'd needs to be unwrapped with the `default` property on the imported esModule (said another way, the instantiation would have to be `new PdfjsWorker.default()`

I was able to mitigate this with the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` plugin, which is able to re-write the require statement based on a regex match/replace, which is matching the original require string and replacing it with one that sets the `worker-loader` option `esModule=false`, followed by the absolute path to the `pdf.worker.js` file on the local system:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /worker-loader!\.\/build\/pdf\.worker\.js$/,
  "worker-loader?esModule=false!" + path.join(__dirname, "../", "node_modules", "pdfjs-dist", "build", "pdf.worker.js")
)
```

It's important to match the complete original require string of `/worker-loader!\.\/build\/pdf\.worker\.js$/` and not just the `pdf.worker.js` part, because you could end up in an infinite replace loop.

You need to fix the replacement string to be a proper path for your project, which would *probably* be

```js
"worker-loader?esModule=false!" + path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "pdfjs-dist", "build", "pdf.worker.js")
```

I have a `../` in my path because this code is being executed inside storybooks `.storybook/` folder, so I have go up a directory to get to `node_modules/`

And with those two changes, everything for PDF.js seems to be working.

And lastly, if you want to ignore the warnings about the missing `FetchCompileWasmPlugin` and `FetchCompileAsyncWasmPlugin` modules, you can setup the webpack `IgnorePlugin` to just ignore these imports, my assumption is they're WASM based and not actually needed

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /FetchCompileWasmPlugin$/ }),
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /FetchCompileAsyncWasmPlugin$/ })
]
```

I'm guessing there might be some out-of-date mismatch of `worker-loader` and the modules in the currently installed Webpack version, but these WASM modules don't seem to be necessary for our purposes

Comment: Wow, a) thanks a lot for your detailed description @Alex and b) I hope I'll be able to put that into place.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using a cdn then use this

```
import pdfJS from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js';
pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.js';
```

Make sure to import minified versions on production

```
import pdfJS from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.min.js';
pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js';
```

Or you can just use minified versions all the time

Comment: Thanks @zoran404 but I am already using the CDN approach. As the guys at Mozilla pointed out it's a bit risky for production.

Comment: It looks like the `esModule=false` setting has now been added to upstream pdf.js: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/external/dist/webpack.js#L19

Answer (score 1):

It worked with:

```
var pdflib = require('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js');
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
pdflib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new pdfjsWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

if webpack is failing because of optional chaining consider pointing to the legacy version which omits modern syntax.

`import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js'`

instead of

`import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist'`

Comment: Thanks. Even though I'm using modern syntax (building from a module/ESM/.mjs file), I still had to use the legacy build versions in order to avoid a `Unexpected token '='` error when building using `pdfjs-dist` v2.13.216.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

> node_modules/pdfsj-dist/package.json

In

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8" -> Version
 },
```

Install version

> npm i worker-loader@3.0.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will break when the user does the next package fetch, as the `package.json` will get overwritten. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095/1974224