# TWISTLOCK Issue for lodash package while deploying

Tags: node.js, express, npm, jenkins-pipeline, lodash

While deploying NODE code getting package vulnerability issue for lodash.
I have updated lodash package version to latest version 4.17.21 but, still showing vulnerability issue .
Below is the error.

lodash 4.17.19 High Fixed IN 4.17.21

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm