# Printing pdf with printJS in chrome with --kiosk-printing enabled always failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, printjs

I try to print a pdf with --kiosk-printing enabled in chrome. The pdf is local available.

Here is my test-code:

```
<button onClick="printJS('assets/pdf-sample.pdf')">
    Print
</button>
```

When i run the print, Chrome is showing the message

> Print Failed
>
> Something went wrong when trying to print. Please check your printer and try again.

I use the newest version of Chrome: 91.0.4472.164 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

Does anyone know what could be the problem here and how I could solve it?

Comment: This is happening for kiosk mode only, please post the solution if you come across any, I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me,

I applied a patch, in the print-js module.

For applying the patch,

In `node_modules/print-js/dist/print.js` line number 259, replace the line

```js
iframe.remove()
```

to

```js
setTimeout(()=>{iframe.remove()},10000); // you can change the delay.
```

Now, to apply the patch,

```
 npx patch-package print-js
```

Also, add the following in the script section of your package.json to automatically patch the dependency when you execute "npm install".

```
"postinstall": "npx patch-package"
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567504/7092628