# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe') when using ngx-notification-bar

Tags: angular

I have implemented the notification bar, using the steps mentioned in this [ngx-notification-bar documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-notification-bar)

In the `app.component.ts` file, the following part of the code is there

```
this.notificationBarService.create({ message: '<b>Free Shipping </b>', type: NotificationType.Info, allowClose: true, autoHide: false, hideOnHover: false, isHtml: true });
```

In the `app.component.html` file, the following part of the code is there

```
<notification-bar
  [ngStyle]="{ height: '3px', background: 'white' }"
></notification-bar>
```

**I am able to see the notification bar on my page. But when I am going to any other page (or component) from the `app.component.html` page, I am getting this below error in the console and the components are not loading, rather a blank screen is there**

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe')
    at NotificationBarComponent.ngOnDestroy (ngx-notification-bar.js:165)
    at executeOnDestroys (core.js:14405)
    at cleanUpView (core.js:14304)
    at destroyViewTree (core.js:14073)
    at destroyLView (core.js:14255)
    at RootViewRef.destroy (core.js:15120)
    at ComponentRef$1.destroy (core.js:34191)
    at RouterOutlet.deactivate (router.js:9122)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRouteAndOutlet (router.js:4023)
    at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRouteAndItsChildren (router.js:3981)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41632)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

As far as I can understand, it is related to not calling `ngOnDestroy()`. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: in what lifecycle step do you call `this.notificationBarService.create`

Comment: @Timon I am calling this service in `ngOnInit(): void { this.notificationBarService.create({ message: '<b>Free Shipping </b>', type: NotificationType.Info, allowClose: true, autoHide: false, hideOnHover: false, isHtml: true }); }`

Comment: I think it's a library issue. `NotificationBarComponent` component is in the library.

Comment: @navnath yes, its in the library. But how can I solve this error, as because of this my other components are not functioning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm

Comment: It's not a good solution but you can add `<notification-bar>` in the shared component like footer where it will not be destroyed until the app is closed, so u you won't get the error of unsubscribe.

Comment: @navnath adding `<notification-bar>` in the footer component also gives me the same error ;-| Or is there any other way I can add the notification bar at the top of my page ?