# Prevent changes made in NPM package if somebody does npm install

Tags: npm

I have made changes in an NPM package. How can I avoid those changes going back to normal if somebody does `npm install`? I don't want any changes in a specific package if somebody does `npm install`. I did `npm install` and all changes made manually were reverted.

Comment: How are they going to get access to your modified version of the package? Maybe you could make a fork, publish and install that fork instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a node module installed via npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a PR in the package repository, and expect the author to approve it.

When you locally change the package content inside your node_modules, it's going to be overwritten by `npm install`.

Comment: is there a method to not update package automatically

Comment: That's going to depend largely on what change you're making - it might not be something the maintainers will accept.