# How to edit the source code from node modules dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

all! I currently met a difficulty with my project. I want to modify the code of a component from a UI library (like Semantic-UI, Material-UI). What I do now is just edited the code from the `node_modules`. But the reality is no matter how I change the code from node_modules, my project will not be affected. Why this will

Comment: JS code? css code?

Comment: JS code, I want to modify ```Vuetify```.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302095/14671536 Everything is described in this post

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because most modules have build process which you need to run before using them. Also editing a module directly is not a good idea because any change you do to them is guaranteed to be lost after next `npm install`.

As Vuetify is a MIT licensed, I suggest to fork its [GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) project and then publish it as your own npm package.