# How to add console.log inside node_modules in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

I am currently working on a Next.js project with a node module that contains some functions. I am trying to debug a node_module library by adding some console.log inside of the module.

I removed cache and restarted server, but that changes for log don't change the result in my app. How can I get the console logs to show up properly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Node module may have dist folder.

If so, let build module inside of itself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread is helping out. [How to edit a node module installed via npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm)

What has been working for me:

1. Disable development server
2. Make changes to node_module (e.g. insert console.log())
3. Delete .next folder
4. Run `npm run build && npm run start`