# making changes in js file in dependency in laravel vuejs app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vite

In my laravel vuejs app, i have installed "vue3-easy-data-table" and there are 2 files "vue3-easy-data-table.js" and "vue3-easy-data-table.js.map" inside node_modules.vite\deps\ ,

I have made some changes in "vue3-easy-data-table.js" for my own requirement but these changes are not getting reflected in the vue3-easy-data-table.js.map file which I believe is rendering on production, I have ran npm run build, cleared cache still not js.map file is updated, what should I do?

(PS, I am noob so don't mind me asking silly questions, I am learning VueJs + Laravel)

I ran NPM Run Build but not worked

Edit : So it turns out I was editing wrong file, I should be editing the dist folder js file --> node_modules\vue3-easy-data-table\dist\vue3-easy-data-table.es.js , thanks this worked fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a node module installed via npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300137/how-to-edit-a-node-module-installed-via-npm)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` in your project directory and then try again.

Comment: So it turns out I was editing wrong file, I should be editing the dist folder js file --> node_modules\vue3-easy-data-table\dist\vue3-easy-data-table.es.js , thanks!