# Requiring node modules locally

Tags: node.js, npm

When working with modules already registered on NPM, the process of including them is easy: run `npm install <package>` and then add `var package = require('<package>')`

However, I'm not sure of the way to "set things up" when working on my own module. I'm not ready to publish to NPM but I do want to `require` the module in the same way as outlined before.

Therefore, I've completed the following steps:

1. Created a sub-directory inside the `node_moduels` directory for my module
2. Added a `package.json` file (via npm init) inside this new directory
3. Included a `dependencies` section in the `package.json` file

Is this the correct approach to using node modules locally.

Also, when I run `npm install` the dependencies do not appear to be detected in my module's package.json file - I assume this is an issue with the way I've gone about things?

Answer (score 5):

I would not suggest putting it in the `node_modules` directory. This folder should be excluded from your source control.

Here's a minimal end to end example.

Put this file wherever you like. I suggest a 'lib' folder within your directory structure

**myModule.js**

```
module.exports = function(callback){
    return callback("hello there");
};
```

Then, wherever you want to use it:

**app.js**

```
var myModule = require('./lib/myModule');

myModule.sayHello(function(hello) {
    console.log(hello);
});
```

Now, if you run `node app.js` your console output will be:

> hello there

As your `myModule` grows, you can refactor this into a separate set of files, create an package.json for it, and publish it to NPM

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it looks like this is what you want

[Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json)

So, based on that, along with our above example, edit your `package.json` as follows

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "myModule": "file:../lib/myModule"
  }
}
```

Then you can `require` as:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
```

If / when you publish `myModule` to npm, you can just change your package.json

**ANOTHER EDIT**

As another alternative, you can specify git urls in your package.json without publishing to NPM

[Use Git dependencies with npm and Node on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243527/use-git-dependencies-with-npm-and-node-on-heroku)

Comment: Thanks - but now every time I want to switch from the local version of the module to the one that may eventually get added to NPM I would need to change the require path

Comment: Essentially - I want to include my module in the same way I would if it were being pulled from NPM.

Comment: Didn't see that - will take a look

Comment: So you would still go with your original suggestion and keep the module outside of `node_modules`

Comment: there's also npm link, which may also be what you want

Answer (score 2):

This would be as easy as doing the following:

1. In the root directory of your (unpublished) module execute [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)
2. In the root directory of your module requiring that unpublished module execute `npm link UNPUBLISHED_MODULE_NAME`.

voilà!