# How add a private\custom Node.js module on package.json

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, gyp

I create a custom node.js plugins in c++ using gyp.

My plugin is not published\public yet so it's not describe on package.json.
I need copy it manually on my node_modules... It's not perfect but it works...

How describe it on package.json to allow npm to retrieve it, compile it and made it visible from my node application without publish it ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15806241/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32537577/3001761, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify the dependency directy

```sh
npm install --save /path/to/your/module
```

for more information, consult the [npm-install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description)